# How to know which request comes from which sessions python

Tags: python, session

I want to know if there is any way available so that I can know session id from the requests that are submitted to a server.

For example, an web server is running. Some users are logged in. Each of the user has a distinct session id. They are submitting requests to the server. is it possible to determine to find the session id from the respective requests?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the session id by

```
request.COOKIES['sessionid']
```

hope this will help.